# Automate multiple dependent python program

Tags: python, talend

I've multiple python scripts. Each script is dependent on other i.e. the first script uses output of the second script, the second script uses output of the third and so on. Is there anyway i can link up the scripts such that i can automate the whole process. I came across  **Talend Data Integration Tool** but i can't figure out how to use it. Any reference or help would be highly useful.

Answer (score 0):

You did not state what operating system/platform you are using, but the problem seems like a good fit for `make`.

You specify dependencies between files in your `Makefile`, along with rules on how to generate one file from the others.

Example:

```
# file-1 depends on input-file, and is generated via f1-from-input.py
file-1: input-file
        f1-from-input.py --input input-file --output file-1

# file-2 depends on file-1, and is generated via f2-from-f1.py
file-2: file-1
        f2-from-f1.py < file-1 > file-2

# And so on
```

For documentation, check out the [GNU Make Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/), or one of the million tutorials on the internet.

Answer (score -1):

i found this [link](https://devzoe.wordpress.com/tag/execute-python-script-using-talend/) it show how to call a python script from Talend and use it's output (not sure if it wait for the code to finish) 
The main concept is to
run the python script from Talend Studio
By using tSystem component